# Getting a value from a string in Powershell

Tags: powershell

What I am trying to achieve is load a `.txt` file and get the value for the string `BatchCust1="1"` into my script. To be more precise I only need the `1`, so remove the `BatchCust1=""` characters and keep only the value within the `""`.

I can successfully get the entire string but I am having trouble getting the value out of it. My code currently goes:

```powershell
Get-ChildItem -Path "directory\*.txt" | foreach ($_) 
   {$value = Get-Content $_ | Select-String BatchCust1}
```

Comment: Does this code return `BatchCust1="1"`?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the `-match` operator:

```psh
Get-ChildItem -Path "directory*.txt" | % {
  $value = Get-Content $_ |
             ? { $_ -match 'BatchCust1="(\d+)"' } |
             % { $matches[1] }
}
```

Note that assigning the matches to a variable inside the loop will get you only the number from the last file (several numbers if there is more than one matching line in that file). If you want the numbers from matches in all files, you should change the above to something like this:

```psh
$values = Get-ChildItem -Path "directory*.txt" |
            Get-Content |
            ? { $_ -match 'BatchCust1="(\d+)"' } |
            % { $matches[1] }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex like this

```
Get-Content .\directory*.txt |%{[regex]::matches($_,'BatchCust1="(.)"').Groups[1].Value}
```